# Replace column names with player1, player2, player3 in for loop

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm

I have a dataframe that consists of columns:

```
print(players_hrpm_all.columns)

['minute', 'kiki fleuren', 'noor driessen', 'loyce bettonvil',
       'frode vd schans', 'ilse kuijt', 'alina sendar', 'fleur kuijt',
       'sonja kuijt', 'jamy de kock', 'ellen meeringa', 'jill bettonvil',
       'charlotte van kleef', 'quarter']
```

I want to change only the columns with playernames, which I wrote the following code for:

```
player_columns = [col for col in players_hrpm_all.columns if ' ' in col]
print(players_columns)

['kiki fleuren', 'noor driessen', 'loyce bettonvil', 'frode vd schans', 'ilse kuijt', 'alina sendar', 'fleur kuijt', 'sonja kuijt', 'jamy de kock', 'ellen meeringa', 'jill bettonvil', 'charlotte van kleef']
```

I want to iterate over all the names in this list and change them into:

```
['player1', 'player2', ... ]
```

I have tried several things, but I couldnt get it to work...
Here are some things I tried:

```
def incrementer():
    counter = 0
    def increment():
        nonlocal counter
        counter += 1
        return counter
    return increment

increment = incrementer()

increment() #1
increment() #2

player = "player"

for column in players_hrpm_all[players_columns]:
    players_hrpm_all = players_hrpm_all.rename(columns = {column : player+str(increment())})

print(players_hrpm_all.columns)


Index(['minute', 'player1', 'player2', 'player3', 'player4', 'player5',
       'player6', 'player7', 'player8', 'player9', 'player10', 'player11',
       'player12', 'quarter'],
      dtype='object')
```

Comment: player is a string and increment() returns an integer. You need to convert increment() to a string.

Comment: Thanks that made it work! I also forgot to assign to the df, inside the for loop. I've edited the result